# Installing and importing multiple versions of a Python package

Tags: python, pip, package, version, dataiku

I am using Dataiku DSS v6.0 which uses `pandas==0.23` and this cannot be manually upgraded. I am also trying to use `modin==0.6`, which is only compatible with `pandas==0.25`. I have tried using `modin==0.3` which requires `pandas==0.23`, but this older version is throwing exceptions with some of the pandas methods I am calling.

Is there any workaround to this? Can I somehow force `modin==0.6` to accept `pandas==0.23`? Otherwise is there a way in which I can install both `pandas==0.23` and `pandas==0.25` and force DSS to use 0.23 and modin to use 0.25?

Comment: Is this helpful [https://github.com/mitsuhiko/multiversion](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/multiversion)?

Comment: This package is built for Python 2.x, and I am using 3.6.4 and so pip3 cannot find the package. Also, I wouldn't trust using a package that hasn't been updated in 9 years!

Comment: I am unable to find any relevant solution. This [article](https://medium.com/knerd/the-nine-circles-of-python-dependency-hell-481d53e3e025) talks about this kind of problem. I will research the topic and maybe I'll code a solution myself.

Comment: It might be possible, but as far as I know, it's going to be difficult. Mitsuhiko's _multiversion_ is an interesting approach. You could also try and see how far you get with this: ["Multi-version installs" from _PyPA_'s _Python Packaging User Guide_](https://packaging.python.org/guides/multi-version-installs/). Otherwise by hacking some custom importers with [_importlib_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), some examples here: https://pymotw.com/3/sys/imports.html#custom-importers

Answer (score 0):

Dataiku is provided with  a concept of  c[ode environments](http://%5Bhttps://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/code-envs/operations-python.html). by using this feature you can have a separated set of dependancies for your own code or for other specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DSS 8.0.0 [Pandas 1.0 is supported](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/release_notes/8.0.html#support-for-pandas-1-0)

However, recents versions of `modin` rely on more recents version of `pandas`; `modin==0.8.0` allows `pandas==1.0.5` so that the most recent version of `modin` compatible with DSS as of today