# Use different version of python package in the same environment

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip, package, dependencies

I need to have different versions of `elasticseach-dsl` installed in the same virtualenv. I would like to be able to import them using some sort of alias:

```
import elasticsearch_dsl1
import elasticsearch_dsl2
import elasticsearch_dsl5
```

I was thinking to create packages called `elasricsearch_dsl*` and in their `setup.py` add install requirements for the proper version of `elasticsearch_dsl` but when I install the packages it results in a conflict because all my packages require different versions of the same library.
I have no clue on how to proceed and if this is possible.

Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052638/installing-and-importing-multiple-versions-of-a-python-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem.

- I downloaded the source code of the `elasticsearch-dsl` libraries of different versions
- Then changed the import statements to use `elasticsearch1`, `elasticsearch2` etc.libraries instead of `elasticsearch` v1.x and v2.x

```
# example `elasticsearch-dsl` v5.4.0
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch #  --> from elasticsearch5 import Elasticsearch
```

- Modified the `setup.py` to change the dependencies from `elasticsearch` to `elasticsearch1`, `elasticsearch2` and so on for each version of the `elasticsearch-dsl`

I've been very lucky because of the existence of `elasticsearch1`, `elasticsearch2`... otherwise I would have to repeat the same procedure for them. And more lucky for the compatibility of dependencies of the various versions of the library.

I'm not proud of this hack but it worked.

#### *setup.py*

An example of a `setup.py` file for `elasticsearch-dls==7.3.0`, then `elasticsearch-dsl7`

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

VERSION = (7, 3, 0)
__version__ = VERSION
__versionstr__ = ".".join(map(str, VERSION))

f = open(join(dirname(__file__), "README"))
long_description = f.read().strip()
f.close()

install_requires = [
    "six",
    "python-dateutil",
    "elasticsearch7",  # before "elasticsearch>=7.0.0,<8.0.0"    <---
    # ipaddress is included in stdlib since python 3.3
    'ipaddress; python_version<"3.3"',
]

tests_require = [
    "mock",
    "pytest>=3.0.0",
    "pytest-cov",
    "pytest-mock<3.0.0",
    "pytz",
    "coverage<5.0.0",
]

setup(
    name="elasticsearch-dsl7", #    <---
    description="Python client for Elasticsearch",
    license="Apache-2.0",
    url="https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-dsl-py",
    long_description=long_description,
    version=__versionstr__,
    author="Honza Král",
    author_email="honza.kral@gmail.com",
    maintainer="Seth Michael Larson",
    maintainer_email="seth.larson@elastic.co",
    packages=find_packages(where=".", exclude=("test_elasticsearch_dsl*",)),
    python_requires=">=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*",
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
    ],
    install_requires=install_requires,
    test_suite="test_elasticsearch_dsl.run_tests.run_all",
    tests_require=tests_require,
    extras_require={"develop": tests_require + ["sphinx", "sphinx_rtd_theme"]},
)
```

Comment: "_And more lucky for the compatibility of dependencies of the various versions of the library._" Yes, that is the very important bit. If that works, good for you. They all depend only on _urllib3_ (more or less), so that is incredibly lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

It is not possible.